# How to set values in a data frame based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my data

```
     customer_id       feature_1        feature_2      feature_3
0    1                 78               73             63
1    2                 79               71             66
2    2                 82               76             69
3    3                 43               32             53
4    3                 63               42             54
```

I want to label the dataframe one by one. For example, for index = 3, target is Bad

```
     customer_id       feature_1        feature_2      feature_3     target
0    1                 78               73             63
1    2                 79               71             66
2    2                 82               76             69
3    3                 43               32             53            bad
4    3                 63               42             54
```

Basically, I do the process of pulling out one by one with my anotation specialsit

Best regards

Comment: Is there any duplication? if yes why no one label this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `set_value` function

```
syntax format is: `DataFrame.set_value(index, col, value, takeable=False)[source]`
```

So for your question the answer would be

```
df.set_value(3, 'target', 'bad')
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can add empty column first, then fill a cell with desired value

```
df['target'] = ''
df['target'].iloc[3] = 'bad'
```